# Postman - Leading zeros being removed from CSV data file

Tags: csv, postman

I'm trying to run my collection using a CSV data file. Some of the data has leading zeros (e.g. 003883) but when I choose the CSV file in Postman and preview the file, the leading zeros have been removed.

Opening the file in a text editor shows that the zeros are present.

Is there a workaround for this?

Comment: Please add some code and what you have tried already.

Comment: I've tried the following:
Created the table in Excel, save in CSV format - Zeros are removed. 
Created the data in text editor using comma seperators. Data previews OK in Postman (i.e. zeros are visible), but SEND request fails (same data works fine in JSON format)

Answer (score 1):

Write your numbers in Excel as "003883","0234","0235"

Answer (score 0):

While it is not the standard way (althought there is not really a csv standard), you can write your numbers as `="003883",="0234",="0235"`.

This way Excel (and probably others) will preserve the leading zeros.

Comment: Tried that, but still doesn't work. CSV files don't recognise formulas, so leading zeros get lost as soon as the file is saved as a CSV.

Comment: The closest I've gotten is to create the table in a text editor, and save the text file with the .csv extension. When I preview this file in Postman, the format looks correct, the leading zeros are visible, but the request still fails. So it seems this is as much an issue with how Postman reads the CSV file as anything.

Answer (score 0):

Ran in to the same issue with Postman Runner, had to switch my .csv files over to .json in order for this to work.